# How to intercept STOMP requests in Spring Api Gateway

Tags: authentication, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-cloud-gateway

I've been struggling with trying to modify STOMP requests which go through Spring Api Gateway and didn't find appropriate way.

Here the main idea: I have a microservice which can receive http requests(rest) and websocket connections. But users don't communicate with that microservice directly, they go through the api-gateway. The gateway authenticates users(OAUTH2), create specific headers with user's data(user id, for example) and send the request forward. The main point here is an authentication and a websocket. I know how to authenticate a websocket connection request in a microservice which is a websocket-server - we use ChannelInterceptor. But in my case, I want that every request which goes through the api-gateway would be being authenticated and final endpoints receive authenticated requests, includes websockets.

So, what i tried to do: i tried to handle a websocket request by ApiGateWayFilter, extract the authorization header to authenticate, add headers with user data and send the request forward. But, ApiGatewayFilter doesn't allow me to even see any data from the connection stomp request i create by javasript because that data is in STOMP layer, not in a http.

So, if anyone could direct me to the "right way" how to do it, i would really appreciate that.